# Laravel Blade how not to show duplicate value in table

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have Customer, Policy and Motorbike models. When I display the Policy order by Category and Customer, I got many rows with same Category's name and Customer's name as the photo below:
[image]

I want to show Customer's name and Category's name only at the first row. I found a video to show how to do this but I lost it for long time. Much appriciated for any help!

Comment: Yes, your category name and customer name is the same, but your `goi bao hiem` and `tong phi BH` is different? Please add your query to your questions.

Comment: I see. This is not about the query but a trick to prevent showing the duplicate value on html table only. @KevinYobeth

Comment: It is not duplicate if the other field value is different

Comment: Sorry if my English is good enough. I dint mean the duplicated row.

Comment: If you are using model with relationship, you could use nested for loop on your blade. It's much simpler.